# What is a GDA, and how can I determine if it's been applied to a workstation?

Tags: excel, vba, datasource, mcafee

Our workstations (Win 10, Office 2016) are on the DoD NMCI network. For a few weeks, some users have reported issues with linking Excel to data sources or programmatically creating a workbook using VBA. When I sent a trouble report to NMCI I received a response stating it's a known issue caused by a recent "GDA for McAfee". It went on to state that "GDA CMW00184993" has been issued and that the problem will be resolved once it is complete and replicated across the network. I take that to mean it's currently being pushed and that some workstations have it and some yet don't. That would explain why some users are not experiencing the issue, in spite of all users being on the same version and build.

What does "GDA" stand for? Is there a way to determine if "GDA CMW00184993" has been applied to a workstation (other than the Excel functions working again)?

Comment: Speculating based on context: GDA = Government Directed Action, CMW = Custom Maintenance Wizard (term stems from Office 2003, later versions call this the Office Customization Tool). Exactly what they're referring to with the number (and how to check for its deployment) can probably not be determined just from that alone.

Comment: NMCI is a restricted intranet. I doubt you would get help regarding GDA online

Comment: [Totally Unrelated](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a579796.pdf) I was reading about those acronyms in this link. Interesting :D

Comment: Thanks JM. That all makes sense. I tried Googling "GDA" and got nothing close to anything IT related. Although the Urban Dictionary did have an interesting term lol.

Comment: I was hoping it would be listed somewhere like the Update History in settings.